# Unknown CTA IDs in Facebook Analytics for Apps

Tags: bots, metrics, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-analytics, facebook-call-to-action

I'm using FAfA to track my Messenger bot's metrics and set up custom events to do so. So far so good :)

I've noticed that prior to mine, FAfA recorded events and assigned IDs to my bot's CTAs such as `cta1_EntBusinessMessageWithItems_408510376182130_0` or `cta1_EntMessengerCommerceCTAList_1280259528710236_0`.

To be more specific, here's an excerpt of [the list that prompts when I visit my "Event Debugging" section and filters by "Messenger bot CTA clicked"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNvOo.png)

What I've noticed so far :

- There are three types of "Messenger bot call to action" : `platform_api`, `messenger_composer` and `structured_menu`
- There are two categories of `cta1_` IDs: `cta1_EntBusiness...`who only pops with a `platform_api` "Messenger bot CTA Type" and `cta1_EntMessenger...`
- In `cta1_EntMessengerCommerceCTAList_1280259528710236_0`, the last digit is not an index. My first thought was to change it as this kind of ID is often associated with a `structured_menu` "Messenger bot CTA type`, index 0 would have represented the first button of the Messenger bot's menu, index 1 the second and so on.
- As seen on the image posted above, there are different kind of "Click on a Messenger bot call to action" : `postback_cta_success`, `postback_send_failed`, `postback_failed`, `postback_cta_clicked` and `composer_cta_double_tapped`.
- When creating a segment in my "Retention" section, everything gets messed up with the events parameters : "Messenger bot CTA type" shows values from "Messenger bot CTA clicked" and "Messenger bot CTA ID" shows values from "Messenger bot CTA type" !
- Howevever, I tried copy & paste a CTA ID generated by FAfA in "Messenger bot CTA ID" event's parameter and it worked : a percentage more or less important of my audience were picked up.

I can deal with the bugs in my "Retention" section but **I can't find which CTA in my bot is linked to the CTA IDs FAfA has generated** : What action performed the user when `cta1_EntBusinessMessageWithItems_408510376182130_0` successfully happened ? Which button with this `cta1_EntMessengerCommerceCTAList_1280259528710236_0`ID the user clicked ?

No ID has been set up as it seems you just can't do it : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/postback

I also did some researches on Stack & Google about the types of CTA, their IDs etc... Found nothing helpful. I'm sure I'm not the only one to face this problem with FAfA, especially among the guys who are building bots and desperately need to tracks their metrics... Please help !

Comment: Answer from Facebook Support : "Unfortunately the ID displayed was not done intentionally, but you should be able to track the message containing the CTA with the message ID." I reopened the case to eventually get a better answer as "message ID" doesn't exist... If anyone got a lead about this mess, I'm all ears.

Comment: We ran into a very similar issue just now. Bots randomly don't respond and the FB event debugger shows CTAs similarly to what's mentioned above. @DFATPUNK did you ever figure out what caused that for you?

Comment: Nope @MikeNikles :/ Since their reply, nothing changed. We're only focused now on our custom events to track our bot's activity. It's really weird to have no answer/fix to this after all this time and tbh, I don't really trust their analytics since this.